# AngularJS $location keeps resetting my URL to my previous path

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using jquery-pjax with AngularJS, and when I click on some `<a>` tag, the plugin catch it correctly - get the content - and changes the URL just fine.

Problem is, when I just add $location to my controller ( not using it at all inside the controller ):

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   # before
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {  # after
```

Now when I click on the `<a>` tag, PJAX plugin catches the event - get the content - changes the URL - just fine.
But after 2 seconds that it was completed, I see the new URL, but then something is changing the path back to previous page in the history ( like I clicked "back").

Now - only the URL changes, the new content is still there ...

When I take out the $location from the controller, everything works fine again ...
any clue ?

## EDIT 1

After struggling with this for a while, I noticed that this behavior happens only when I use $location in the controller assigned to the `<body>` tag like so:

```
<body ng-controller="SomeCtrl">    # I used $location here
  ... some html ...
  <div ng-controller="SomeSubCtrl"></div>
</body>
```

And due to the following code outside of AngularJS, to make sure the new segment was assign with a controller

```
var ngRefresh = function() {
    var scope = angular.element("body").scope();
    var compile = angular.element("body").injector().get('$compile');

    compile($("body").contents())(scope);
    scope.$apply();
};
```

When disabling this function - the URL doesn't change ... but I need it so new controllers will be activated for the new segments ...
So I still don't understand why this is happening ...

## EDIT 2 workaround

Since I don't really need to use the $location services, I ended up using $window instead

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {
   .....
   $scope.path = $window.location.pathname;
   .....
```

this doesn't change my URL after PJAX is completed. and I'm fine with using this code instead.

Maybe there's some special features for $location when used with Angular's routes, and I'm not using routes at all ... so maybe $location is behaving strange .. don't know.

I just noticed: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11075

Comment: liely a bad idea using a mini framework that interacts with history on top of angular. Why not just use angular for the ajax?

Comment: I'm using pjax not ajax, mainly for the PushState ( since I can retrieve html via ajax too ) If I'll use angular's ajax - I will have to write the pushstate myself ... also pjax catches all the a tags and run the request and drop it where i want automatically ... so I don't want to write that myself as well for ajax ....